# Unable to create bean for org.springframework.cloud.gcp.vision.CloudVisionTemplate

Tags: java, spring-boot, google-cloud-vision, google-developers-console

required a bean of type 'org.springframework.cloud.gcp.vision.CloudVisionTemplate' that could not be found

**VisionController.java**

```
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.cloud.gcp.vision.CloudVisionTemplate;

@RestController
public class VisionController {
    
    @Autowired
    private ResourceLoader resourceLoader;

    @Autowired
    private CloudVisionTemplate cloudVisionTemplate;
}
```

**build.gradle**

```
dependencies {
implementation group: 'org.springframework.cloud', name: 'spring-cloud-gcp-dependencies', version: '1.2.8.RELEASE', ext: 'pom'
implementation group: 'org.springframework.cloud', name: 'spring-cloud-gcp-starter-vision', version: '1.2.8.RELEASE'
}
```

**application.properties**

```
spring.cloud.gcp.credentials.location=file:src/main/resources/key.json
spring.cloud.gcp.project.id=MyProjectKey
```

***Exception***

Field cloudVisionTemplate in com.vision.lens.VisionController required a bean of type 'org.springframework.cloud.gcp.vision.CloudVisionTemplate' that could not be found.

The injection point has the following annotations:
- @org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)

Action:

Consider defining a bean of type 'org.springframework.cloud.gcp.vision.CloudVisionTemplate' in your configuration.

Comment: Does this [link1](https://cloud.google.com/vision/docs/adding-spring), [link2](https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-static/spring-cloud-gcp/1.2.0.M2/reference/html/spring-cloud-gcp.html#_google_cloud_vision) and [link3](https://www.knowledgefactory.net/2023/03/spring-boot-google-cloud-vision-integration-example.html) help you in resolving the issue?

Answer (score 0):

You are using CloudVisionTemplate from the wrong package.

Use

> `import com.google.cloud.spring.vision.CloudVisionTemplate;`

instead of

> `import org.springframework.cloud.gcp.vision.CloudVisionTemplate;`

Here is example of maven POM with correct dependencies:

```
<parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.4</version>
        <relativePath/>
</parent>
    
 <properties>
        <java.version>17</java.version>
        <spring-cloud-gcp.version>4.1.2</spring-cloud-gcp.version>
        <spring-cloud.version>2022.0.1</spring-cloud.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-cloud-dependencies</artifactId>
                <version>${spring-cloud.version}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.google.cloud</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-cloud-gcp-dependencies</artifactId>
                <version>${spring-cloud-gcp.version}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-gcp-starter</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-gcp-starter-vision</artifactId>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
```